# Loop inside an Ansible module

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to create an ECS task definition using the `community.aws.ecs_taskdefinition` I wrote something like this:

```
- name: Create task definition   
  community.aws.ecs_taskdefinition:
    containers:
    - name: First_container
      << container definition >>
    
    - name: "{{ item.service }}"
      essential: true
      image: "{{ user_info.account }}.dkr.ecr.{{ AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/{{ app_name }}-{{ item.service }}"
      environment:
        "{{ item.env_var }}"
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: "{{ item.port_a }}"
        hostPort: "{{ item.port_b }}" 
      with_items:
         - "{{ parameters }}"
```

Basically I want to create **one** task definition with the first container plus all the other defined in ***parameters***.
Unfortunately if I put the with_item as above, it doesn't work and if I put it at the same level of `containers` it will create many revision of the same task definition and each revision will have the first container and only one of those defined in ***parameters***.

Is there any way to achieve this?

edit: for clarification
basically parameter is a list of dictionaries like:

```
parameters : [{service:"service1",env_var:"something",port_a:80,port_b:80} ,
           { service:"service2",env_var:"somethingelse",port_a:3000,port_b:3000}]
```

what I want to achieve is the same as:

```
- name: Create task definition   
  community.aws.ecs_taskdefinition:
    containers:
    - name: First_container
      << container definition >>
    
    - name: "service1"
      essential: true
      image: "{{ user_info.account }}.dkr.ecr.{{ AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/{{ app_name }}-service1"
      environment:
        env_var: "something" 
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 80
        hostPort: 80 
    - name: "service2"
      essential: true
      image: "{{ user_info.account }}.dkr.ecr.{{ AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/{{ app_name }}-service2"
      environment:
        env_var: "somethingelse" 
      portMappings:
      - containerPort: 3000
        hostPort: 3000
```

but because parameters can have many services, I would like to have a loop to deal with it. hope is more clear.

Comment: Difficult to understand what you want. Could you show the result waited and the content of var parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to create a variable and include it in task:

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        containers: "{{ container0 + other_containers.names}}" 
      vars:
        parameters : [{"service":"service1", "env_var":"something", "port_a":80, "port_b":80} ,
                      { "service":"service2", "env_var":"somethingelse", "port_a":3000, "port_b":3000}]      
        container0:
          - name: "First_container"
            other_param: "otherrrrrrs"
        other_containers: >-
            { "names": [
            {%- for p in parameters -%}
            {"name": {
                        "essential": true,
                        "environment": "{{ p.env_var }}",
                        "portMappings": [{ "containerPort": "{{ p.port_a }}", "hostPort": "{{ p.port_b }}" }]  
                      }
            } {{ "" if loop.last else "," }}          
            {%- endfor -%}
            ]}
            
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ containers }}"

    - name: Create task definition   
      community.aws.ecs_taskdefinition:
        containers: "{{ containers }}"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved by creating a jinja template for the task definition play, call it from the playbook, populate with the content of parameters and create a yaml file, then I use include to call this yaml file in the playbook.

Comment: @Domenico yes there are lot of ways to resolv your problem..dont forget to close your question by validating the answer ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `{{ parameters }}` variables directly inside a playbook.

Workaround will be:

```
loop:
  - { service: "service1", env_var: "something", port_a: 80, port_b: 80 }
  - { service: "service2", env_var: "somethingelse", port_a: 3000, port_b: 3000 }
```

or else register the variables in inventory file or add it to your playbook. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56061116/looping-over-list-data-in-ansible-playbooks)

Comment: I do access the parameters variable because I pass it as --extra-var. the problem with 
```loop:
  - { service: "service1", env_var: "something", port_a: 80, port_b: 80 }
  - { service: "service2", env_var: "somethingelse", port_a: 3000, port_b: 3000 }```
is that I don't know in advance how long is the parameters list, could be 2,3 or any number. And however this will create two revision of the same task definition, which is not what I want. What I need is one task definition with as many container a defined in parameters.